# Display list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently learning C# .net and I'm attempting to display a distinct list of states, but I just can't figure out how to do this.

In my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult StateListDistinct()
        {
            var distinctStates = (from w in db.Contact_Addresses
                                  select new { State = w.Site_address_state}).Distinct();

            return View(distinctStates.ToList());
        }
```

And in my view I have:

```
@model List<String>
<table class="table">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I'm getting the error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

What do I need to do to display a list of states?

Comment: `select new w.Site_address_state` assuming Site_address_state is of type string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view is expecting a list of strings, but what you're feeding it is a list of anonymous types.

Using method syntax, what you're trying to achieve can be done this way:

```
db.Contact_Addresses.Select(state =>state.Site_address_state).Distinct().ToList();
```

This should do the trick as well:

```
var distinctStates = (from w in db.Contact_Addresses
                              select w.Site_address_state).Distinct().ToList();
```